Weird problem with bevelling - corners and edges become jagged
I'm very new to Blender. I'm modelling something by following this tutorial and I'm having issues with bevelling. This step happens at 2:30 into the video.
Here's what they do:

In Edit Mode, they select everything (one shape, a cube) with "a" then bevel it with Ctrl+B to bevel the corners.
They go into object mode and press Ctrl+A to apply the scale.
They go back into edit mode, press a then Ctrl+ B again and this bevels the edges instead of the corners this time.

This last point is where I'm having issues. When they do this in the video it lets them bevel the edges instead of the corners. It looks like this:

When I do it the shape freaks out and looks like this:

Am I missing something here? Anyone know what's going on?
Thanks


Hard to tell exactly from the screenshot, but it looks like you have some messed up geometry there...some parts seem to be separate from the others, I would suspect duplicate geometry and maybe inverted normals in some areas. Apart from that, in the reference they are just beveling a slight offset while you are going much further and the beveled parts expand into each other and start overlapping.

@GordonBrinkmann Thanks for the reply, any idea on how to fix it? To get to that point, I just took the default cube, resized it on the x axis then did the steps I mentioned above. There's no other geometry in the scene. I tried flipping and recalculating the normals but it didn't solve the problem. When the YouTuber moved the mouse a lot to show the impact of the bevelling jthe sides curved up smoothly in a ramp and didn't have the geometry issues I have so there must be something I'm missing on my shape. Also just added the blend file to the post.

Have you applied the scale after resizing it with Ctrl+A > Apply > Scale?

From your Blend file, it looks as if you're trying to bevel on top of another bevel which will produce the weird results you're seeing. Start again with a new cube, scale it and apply the scale before you go into Edit mode and do any bevelling.

It's also better practice to use a Bevel Modifier in combination with bevel weights or with the limit method set to Angle. Then you get the beveled edge, but if you need to edit it later, add/remove geo etc you can easily do so.

@Jakemoyo Probably, but this question came up after following a tutorial. As a beginner having problems following a tutorial I would not expect him to ignore what is shown there and use a modifier instead. But maybe he could watch tutorials about using modifiers. //EDIT: Oh dear, I just quickly looked at the tutorial and the person there seems to be a bit clueless as well... applying scale is definitely not something she cares about.

@GordonBrinkmann Yeah, lmao those tutorials can be a bit of a gamble sometimes :D

Yeah I agree with @JohnEason - The mesh you're trying to bevel already appears to have a bevel applied to it which creates a ton more geometry. Ctrl-A will select all of that geometry and then Ctrl-B will attempt to bevel each of those edges which is guaranteed to result in a mess. Start over with a clean cube with scale applied.
Aside from that, they instruct to change the pivot point which is unnecessary and has nothing to do with applying scale. This made me a little suspicious of the entire tutorial.

@AaronVDW Ctrl+A does not select all in Edit Mode, it actually does nothing there... A selects everything and Alt+A deselects again (or you could also quickly double-tap A).

Thanks for the help all! Will try all those suggestions, cheers.

@GordonBrinkmann Right you are, thanks for the correction.
